# Return the number of different initial letters (case-insensitive) of all names? (Java)

Tags: java, java-stream

I have `.getOwner` and `.displayname` and an Array q for disposal.

How can I return the number of different initial letters (case-insensitive) of all names using streams?

I tried it that way:

```
return q.stream()
        .map(n -> n.getOwner().display_name.length() != 0 n.getOwner().display_name.charAt(0) : ' ')
        .distinct();
```

It's not working.

Comment: you count empty names as a distinct initial letter as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think(you need two more steps) filter if it is an alphabetic to avoid space from condition, and count in the end:

```
long count = q.stream()
        .map(n -> n.getOwner().display_name.length() != 0 ? Character.toLowerCase(n.getOwner().display_name.charAt(0)) : ' ')
        .distinct()
        .filter(Character::isAlphabetic)
        .count();
```

if you accept all characters except space then you can replace filter with:

```
.filter(n -> n != ' ')
```

---

Note: I would recommend to replace `display_name` by `private String displayName;` and use getter and setters instead of calling the attribute directly.

---

#### An ideal Solution:

```
long count = q.stream()
        .map(ClassName::getOwner)
        .map(Owner::getDisplayName)
        .filter(dn -> dn.length() > 0)
        .map(dn -> Character.toLowerCase(dn.charAt(0)))
        .distinct()
        .count();
```

Comment: The “case-insensitive” part is missing…